# Ему казалось, что он понимает то, чего она никак не понимала

Tags: семантика, литература, смысл

Она на самом деле не понимала или ему казалось, что она не понимала?

Answer (score 3):

**Ему казалось, что он понимает то, чего она никак не понимала: именно того, как она могла, сделав несчастие мужа, бросив его и сына и потеряв добрую славу, чувствовать себя энергически-веселою и счастливою.**

Чтобы понять смысл сказанного, надо предложение  прочитать до конца.

Он понимает ее поступок, может как-то объяснить (так ему кажется). А вот она свой поступок, свое поведение понять (и тем более как-то объяснить) не может (так думает автор).

Comment: не автор, а персонаж

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя исключить, что *на самом деле* (= независимо от его мыслей) она "понимала". Из предложения следует только, что *в его восприятии* она не понимала чего-то, а он это же "что-то" понимал.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого стоит разобраться в другом вопросе - к чему относится в этом повествовании "что она не понимала".
Варианты:

- мнение повествователя
- мнение персонажа

Обычно в литературном тексте такое вступление ("ему казалось") дается к описанию состояния персонажа изнутри, далее читатель переносит себя на этого человека и пытается ощутить его состояние. Здесь именно такой случай. Все предложение - цельный образ состояния этого человека. Значит, именно в этом и было намерение автора. Это никак не исключает того, что из контекста может следовать, что она действительно не понимала.

С прочтением "что она не понимала" как мысли самого автора - много сложнее. Для этого автор захотел бы иначе сформулировать свою мысль, чтобы она так же могла быть цельно и недвусмысленно воспринята. Допустим, он бы так и сказал

> Она на самом деле не понимала то, что ему казалось понятным.

Answer (score 0):

Заметим, что "ему казалось" говорит о субъективном восприятии происходящего героем рассказа. А это означает, что объективная реальность могла совпадать с тем, что ему казалось, а могла и не совпадать. Далее, вопрос в том, к чему относятся слова "ему казалось". И здесь нет однозначности. Возможно, она действительно чего-то не понимала, а ему казалось, что он это понимает. Но возможно также, что "ему казалось" относится ко всех ситуации в целом: она чего-то не понимает, а он это понимает. Предложение составлено так, что дать однозначный ответ не представляется возможным.

Дополнение.
Оказывается, это вырванная из контекста цитата из Толстого. Ознакомившись с контекстом, могу добавить следующее. Вне контекста эту фразу можно толковать и так и этак, но это довольно бессмысленное занятие. А в контексте ситуация представлена так, как ее увидел Голенищев, а о позиции автора можно только догадываться. И вообще, подобный литературно-психологический анализ выходит далеко за рамки задач данного сайта.